# cohomology of general linear group over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, group-cohomology

Let $\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ be the group consisting of all $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with non-zero determinant. 
What is the cohomology algebra
$$
H^*(\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_2);\mathbb{Z}_2)?
$$

Could you give any references? Thanks.